# How to pass tExtractjsonfield value to tRestclient url path

Tags: java, rest, api, talend, tmap

Hi am very new to talend tool, I have an Order api url, using tRestclient component I got the Order response and I used tExtractJsonfield component to get the json value, Here order response contains few api url I need to make a call to all the url's How can I do that? any one can help me out with this please??

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details in which API calls you need to add and a screenshot of your current job layout.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the tFlowToIterate Component.

tExtractJsonFields -{row1}-> tFlowToIterate -{iterate}-> tJava

in tJava you add:

```
((String)globalMap.put("orderapiurl")) = ((String)globalMap.get("row1.{value}"));
```

Now e.g. you connect a tHttpRequest component via 'On Component OK' to the tJava component and add

```
((String)globalMap.get("orderapiurl"))
```

as URI.